# Сохранит эффект наведения курсора на ссылку

Tags: css

Здравствуйте! Есть структура меню навигации:

```
<nav id="menu" class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-header"><span id="category" class="visible-xs"><?php echo $text_category; ?></span>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
    <?php if ($category['children']) { ?>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>" class="dropdown-toggle"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-inner">
          <?php foreach (array_chunk($category['children'], ceil(count($category['children']) / $category['column'])) as $children) { ?>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <?php foreach ($children as $child) { ?>
            <li><a class="adrop" href="<?php echo $child['href']; ?>"><?php echo $child['name']; ?></a></li>
            <?php } ?>
          </ul>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>

    </li>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php } ?>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Есть `CSS` свойства при неведении курсора мыши на ссылку меню 1-ого уровня, после чего выпадает меню 2-ого уровня, так вот когда я навожу курсор на ссылки из меню 2-ого уровня у меня пропадает `background-color` у ссылки первого уровня, как этого избежать? Я хочу сохранить `background-color` у ссылки из меню 1-ого уровня. `CSS` свойства для меню:

```
#menu .nav > li > a:hover, #menu .nav > li.open > a {
  background-color: #215289;
  color: #ffc8aa;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
ul > li {
  position: relative;
}
ul > li > a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: #000;
  padding: 12px 25px;
}
ul > li > ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
ul > li:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
ul > li:hover > a {
  background-color: #215289;
  color: #ffc8aa;
}
ul > li > ul > li a:hover {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="#">menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">menu 2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">menu 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">menu 1</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```